# explain in Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c, matrix

Here is my code for matrix multiplication.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  main()
  {
     int a[10][10],b[10][10],c[10][10],m,n,o,i,j,k;
     printf("Enter rows and column for matrix: ");
     scanf("%d%d%d",&m,&n,&o);
     printf("\nEnter elements of matrix 1:\n");
     for(i=0;i<m;i++)
     {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {

                            printf("Enter elements a[%d][%d]: ",i,j);
                    scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }
    }
    printf("\nEnter elements of matrix 2:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<o;j++)
            {
                    printf("Enter elements b[%d][%d]: ",i,j);
                    scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
            }
    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<o;j++)
            {
                    c[i][j]=0;
            }
    }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<o;j++)
            {
                    for(k=0; k<n; ++k)
                    {
                            c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];
                    }
            }
    }
    printf("\nOutput Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<o;j++)
            {
                    printf("%d \t\t ",c[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

My question is in matrix multiplication why we initialize resultant array (`c[i][j]`) into 0 and then also add that resultant array with multiplication of both matrix i.e. `c[i][j] = c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j]`?
Why we cant directly write `c[i][j] = a[i][k]*b[k][j]`?

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize your matrix because each cell is a sum. These sums need initialization.
The initialization is usually zero since you want C=A*B.
you could initialize C with an hypothetical D matrix, you would then obtain C= A*B + D.

edit: note that for a fixed size matrix (said 3x3) you could expand the sum with a simpler expression, and avoid an initialization.
for instance, A and B (and C) are 3x3 matrix, you could write something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<3; ++j){
        c[i][j] = a[i][0]*b[0][j] + a[i][1]*b[1][j] + a[i][2]*b[2][j];
    }    
}
```

This code requires no initialization since `c[i][j]` is fully defined from one single expression.

Answer (score 0):

As Johan pointed out in a comment below, you are iterating over multiple sets of cells in a and b to set a cell in c, and keeping a running total in the process. That is why you need to keep adding to the existing cell value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize `c[i][j]` to zero since you accumulate the results of the most inner loop in that field.

you can integrate the zero loop into the multiply loop.

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<o;j++)
  {
    c[i][j] = 0;
    for(k=0; k<n; ++k)
    {
      c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
  }
}
```

or just memset the region

```
memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));
```

or zero it on itialization;

```
int c[10][10] = {0};
```